# Input is not changing when button is clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am writting a simple counter which adds or mimus for each click on the respective button. However, I cannot make the text input change accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <form>
      <input id="minus" type="button" value="-" onclick="minus()" >
      <input id="num" type="text" name="message" value="10">
      <input id="add" type="button" value="+" onclick="add()" >
  </form>

</div>

<script> 
    var input = document.getElementById("num");


    function add()
    {
        var result = (parseInt(input.value,10) + 1).toString();
        input.value = result;
    }


    function minus()
    {
        var result = (parseInt(input.value,10) - 1).toString();
        input.value = result;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What did I do wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**`element IDs are global variables`**](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html)

As `inline-click` handler expects function to be under `global-scope`(`window.FUNCTION_NAME`), `function-name` can not have same name as value of `ID` attribute

In your example, `add/minus` are `DOMElements/Objects`, not a function hence **`add is not defined`** **`ReferenceError`** is thrown.

```js
console.log(add);
console.log(minus);
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input id="minus" type="button" value="-" onclick="minusCount()" />
    <input id="num" type="text" name="message" value="10">
    <input id="add" type="button" value="+" onclick="addCount()">
  </form>
</div>
```

It is recommended to use `JavaScript-Event-Binding(addEventListener)` instead of `Inline-event-handlers`

```js
var input = document.getElementById("num");
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value = (parseInt(input.value, 10) + 1).toString();
});
minus.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value = (parseInt(input.value, 10) - 1).toString();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input id="minus" type="button" value="-">
    <input id="num" type="text" name="message" value="10">
    <input id="add" type="button" value="+">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same ID name and function name. Please try this. It will work.

```
<div>
<form>
  <input id="minus" type="button" value="-" onclick="minusCount()" />
  <input id="num" type="text" name="message" value="10">
  <input id="adda" type="button" value="+" onclick="addCount()" >
 </form>

</div>

<script> 
var input = document.getElementById("num");


function addCount()
{
    var result = (parseInt(input.value,10) + 1).toString();
    input.value = result;
}


function minusCount()
{
    var result = (parseInt(input.value,10) - 1).toString();
    input.value = result;
}
```